# How to get boundingBox of a QTextTableCell

Tags: qt4

I am using QTextDocument and needs to do some custom hit testing, for that I need to find boundingbox of QTextTableCell but couldn't find any way to figure it out. Can someone throw some light or any ideas on how I should be able to get that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found there wasn't anyway to do it without making any change to Qt code, here is diff of what I had to do.

```
    ==== //local/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/text/qabstracttextdocumentlayout.h#2 (text) ====

    @@ -92,6 +92,11 @@
         virtual QRectF frameBoundingRect(QTextFrame *frame) const = 0;
         virtual QRectF blockBoundingRect(const QTextBlock &block) const = 0;

    +    virtual QRectF cellBoundingRect(QTextTable &table, const QTextTableCell &cell) const
    +    {
    +        return QRectF();
    +    }
    +
         void setPaintDevice(QPaintDevice *device);
         QPaintDevice *paintDevice() const;


    ==== //local/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/text/qtextdocumentlayout.cpp#3 (text) ====

    @@ -3201,6 +3201,17 @@
         return QRectF(pos, data(table)->size.toSizeF());
     }

    +QRectF QTextDocumentLayout::cellBoundingRect( QTextTable &table, const QTextTableCell &cell) const
    +{
    +    Q_D(const QTextDocumentLayout);
    +    if (d->docPrivate->pageSize.isNull())
    +        return QRectF();
    +    d->ensureLayoutFinished();
    +    QTextTableData *td = static_cast(data(&table));
    +    QRectF cellRect = td->cellRect(cell);
    +    return cellRect;
    +}
    +
     QRectF QTextDocumentLayout::frameBoundingRect(QTextFrame *frame) const
     {
         Q_D(const QTextDocumentLayout);

    ==== //local/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/text/qtextdocumentlayout_p.h#1 (text) ====

    @@ -104,6 +104,8 @@

         bool contentHasAlignment() const;

    +    virtual QRectF cellBoundingRect(QTextTable &table, const QTextTableCell &cell) const;
    +
     protected:
         void documentChanged(int from, int oldLength, int length);
         void resizeInlineObject(QTextInlineObject item, int posInDocument, const QTextFormat &format);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a way to get the cell's rect. You need to iterate over the cell contents and join the areas. And finally add the cell's padding. Here is a working example.  But you might have to extend this if your cells contain nested Frames or cells that span multiple rows.

```
QRectF cellBounds(QTextEdit& edit, QTextTable& table, QTextTableCell& cell, bool rowCheck = true) {
    QTextTableFormat tableFormat = table.format();
    qreal cellExtra = tableFormat.cellPadding() /* + tableFormat.border()*/;
    int vOffset = edit.verticalScrollBar()->value();
    QTextBlock next = cell.firstCursorPosition().block();
    QTextBlock last = cell.lastCursorPosition().block();
    QAbstractTextDocumentLayout* layout = edit.document()->documentLayout();
    QRectF bounds;
    while (next.isValid()) {
        bounds = bounds.isNull() ? layout->blockBoundingRect(next) : bounds.united(layout->blockBoundingRect(next));
        if (next == last) {
            break;
        }
        next = next.next();
    }
    if (!bounds.isNull()) {
        bounds.adjust(-cellExtra, -cellExtra, cellExtra, cellExtra);
        bounds.translate(0, -vOffset);
        if(rowCheck) {
            for(int col = 0; col < table.columns(); col++) {
                if(col != cell.column()) {
                    QTextTableCell nextCell = table.cellAt(cell.row(), col);
                    QRectF nextBounds = cellBounds(edit, table, nextCell, false);
                    if(nextBounds.height() > bounds.height())
                        bounds.setHeight(nextBounds.height());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return bounds;
}
```